# Email body is always empty

Tags: javascript, email, mailto

I have the following `formatEmail` function:

```
function formatEmail(attachment, body) {
    body = "test";
    window.location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "?subject=" + self.subject() + "&body=" + body;
}
```

That opens an email on the client machine, the email opens but the body is always empty.

Any idea what can causes that?

Comment: What `self.subject()` returns?

Comment: @Veve The `self.subject()` returns: "Order 111"

Comment: and `emailTo`? You're not passing that with function

Comment: Can you tell me if `emailTo` is defined or not? Because as from seeing your example, you are clearly not passing `emailTo`

Comment: remember that if one of the parameters are empty, the `body` will not be parsed correctly and so will not populate the email body party

Comment: They are all declared in the global function and are not empty

Comment: @Roljhon Thank you, thanks to you I got it to work! I hardcoded the `subject` with `test` and then I got it to work, it must be an invalid character in the subject.. Thank you! Please write it as an answer and I'll accept it...

Comment: @user3378165 great! here you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank God my answer below fixes your issue :)

Just always remember to prevent empty values in the query to avoid misparsing. If the subject value is empty or with invalid characters the next parameter will be misparsed. :)